# Script and function loops through data twice

Tags: loops, python-2.7, xlrd

I am trying to understand if this is a normal behavior in the xlrd mod or if I am misusing something. Here's the code:

```
import xlrd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('exceptions v2.xlsm')

worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
num_rows = worksheet.nrows - 1
curr_row = -1
data = []
print 'begin loop'
while curr_row < num_rows:
    curr_row += 1
    row = worksheet.row(curr_row)
    print row
    data.append(row)

print 'out of loop'
```

When I run the script, it will print `begin loop` and `out of loop` twice along with all the data in my spread sheet.  So in other words, this while loop runs through twice and stops.  I threw a `raise SystemExit` after the print `out of loop` and the script stopped where I would have excepted it to.

Another thought too, the end use is to create a list in python by appending each row from excel to a list (I call it data here) and something I noticed is I am not getting duplicates in my list even though I see the print statements running twice.

Comment: Is this code being called in a function or is this the entire script? Because if this is the entire script there doesn't seem to be a reason for it to print either print statement twice.

If it's in a function it makes sense why you don't have double the data, because the data list is being reset in between loop runs.

Comment: I was trying it as both and getting the same result. However, I was using it as a script at the bottom of my actual program instead of doing it in a new file.  When I opened up a new file and tested it out, everything worked just fine.  But good observation about the list being reset, that was helpful. Apparently I must have something in my program going through everything twice, and I just got hung up on xrld because I am not super familiar with that mod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the answer.  The problem was in my import statements.

I have two files import_kip.py and initialize.py.  I was testing the above xlrd script at the bottom of initialize.py and then importing initialize.py to import_kip.py and then importing import_kip.py to my initialize.py file. So essentially the script was run by both import_kip.py and initialize.py.  And because the script started with `data = []`, it cleared out my list each time it was run so I wasn't getting duplicates.

I know this is confusing but hopefully is helpful for someone who recreates this in some fashion.